# What is the best place to buy a folding bike for $350-$400 in Canada?

Tags: folding-bicycle, canada

I'm looking to buy a folding bike for my commute to work and want to spend $350-400. The bikes at Vela.ca look very good but I want to make sure I get the best deal. 
Shipping costs are also a concern. Vela has a flat rate of $35 which is very low.

Comment: Thanks for posting, but localized questions aren't what we do. If you're concerned with buying a bike on the net, please reword and we'll reopen this.

Comment: to clarify, if you could remove the reference to Toronto from the title, we'll re-open. [It's been suggested](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/97/seeking-consensus-on-closing-problematic-questions/102) I may have closed this too quickly, please don't let that discourage you. :)

Comment: ok edited to "canada" - i hope that's not 'too localized' (http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/60/another-regional-specific-question-are-these-ok-or-not'

Comment: Note: The thinking on how we handle localized questions on this site has changed since the above exchange was posted. These questions are welcome, within reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Downtube](http://www.downtube.com/) is well-thought-of, and they ship internationally. They also accept returns, although you'd be out the money for shipping.

Dahon has several bikes under $400US/$412CAD - the [Boardwalk](http://www.thorusa.com/dahon/current/boardwalk1.htm) and [Eco](http://www.thorusa.com/dahon/current/ecoD7.htm) (and the [7-speed Speed](http://www.thorusa.com/dahon/current/speedd7.htm) is you can stretch your budget a little). Dahon is likely the best choice for a budget folder, and they have [dealers in Canada](http://us.dahon.com/locator/results?distance%5bpostal_code%5d=&distance%5bsearch_distance%5d=20&distance%5bsearch_units%5d=mile&tid=All&country=ca).

Comment: thanks those are some very good suggestions. Ever hear anything about Vela.ca ?

Comment: @Moofoo - no, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest starting with your local bike shop. They're the ones that will do some of the servicing (I'm guessing) and having a good relationship with them is always important. If they can't even come close to pricing or won't get a folding bike for you then your local Craigslist might yield some results.